# Distribution of toys to children, combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you distribute 15 distinct toys among 3 children such that each child can get any no of toys?

The answer is 3^15 but I beg to differ.

Each child can get 0,1,2... or 15 toys and so shouldn't the answer be 16^3. Please point out the flaw in my thinking

Comment: The numbers of toys each kid gets are not independent; for instance they cannot all get $15$ toys. Also it matter which kid gets which toy (it really matters for children, I can assure you), so just counting for each kid won;t do.

Answer (score 3):

The $3^{15}$ comes from (children)^(toys), because each toy can be given to any child independently.  Because of the independence you multiply the possibilities.  You are correct that each child can receive $16$ different numbers of presents but we are concerned with specific arrangements of toys, not just the total number.   Also, the number of toys received by one child is not independent of the number received by another child.  Your $16^3$ would be correct if we gave $0$ to $15$ (indistinguishable) toys to the first child, then $0$ to $15$ to the second child (without regard to how many we gave to the first) and again $0$ to $15$ to the third child.